# Permission error whenever I create a file using Laravel Artisan in my WSL

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, wsl-2, laravel-sail

I am having a weird problem with Laravel Sail on WSL2, if I create a model using the artisan command, whenever I make changes to the file and save it, I am having the following error:

`Failed to save 'TestModel.php': Unable to write file 'vscode-remote://wsl+ubuntu-20.04/home/tarky/projects/qr-project/app/Models/TestModel.php' (NoPermissions (FileSystemError): Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/tarky/projects/qr-project/app/Models/TestModel.php')`

But if I create the file manually in VS Code, it works.

Any ideas why is this happening?

I did `sudo chmod -R 777 projects/qr-project/`

But the error is still happening.

Comment: How about using `chown` to change ownership to your default ubuntu user?

Comment: Already did and the problem persists